# How to search subdirectories for .c files and compile them (shell scripting)

Tags: bash, shell, subdirectory

I need to take an argument which is a directory of the current directory and search its folders and compile any C files in those folders. I'm just beginning shell scripting in Bash and am a little over my head.

So far things I've tried included using find to search for the files and then pipe it to xargs to compile but kept getting an error saying that testing.c wasn't a directory.

```
find ~/directory -name *.c | xargs gcc -o testing testing.c
```

I've also tried ls -R to search folders for .c files but don't know how to then take the paths as arguments to then move to and compile?

Comment: ... Compile them all together into a single object?

Comment: Write a makefile for this kind of task.

Comment: No I don't want them to compile all together Ignacio so I see how that  wouldn't work now anyway. I had a quick google of makefile shx2 but don't think this is an option. The question is for an assignment and just asks for a script.

I think I need to take the output of ls somehow and do an if statement to check if there is indeed .c files and then move that directory and compile them. Would I be on the right track then?

Comment: The command you wrote is going to find .c files below directory and then append their relative paths - as many as will fit in the command line length limit (thought that's huge) - to the `gcc -o testing testing.c` command.   Essentially it'll try to compile them all into a single binary named `testing`, which may not be what you want.  Neither find nor xargs is going to even chdir into the found subdirectories by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find directory -type f -name "*.c" -exec sh -c \
  'cd $(dirname $1);make $(basename $1 .c)' sh {} \;
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `sh` before the `{}`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Something need to be put here to become $0 which whould be confusing to use as dirname and basename arguments. I use `sh` for clarity but it can be any string.

Comment: OK - fair enough...you seem to be correct that you get to specify `$0` as well as the other arguments, and `sh` is at least as good a value for `$0` as any, and better than most.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler s/seem to be/are/

Answer (score 2):

```
find ~/directory -type f -name "*.c" -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' pathname; do
    gcc -o "${pathname%.c}" "$pathname"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As @shx2 suggested, using [`make`](http://lackof.org/taggart/hacking/make-example/) (or some other build system) would arguably be the best approach. You don't want to go compiling files in some source tree without a proper build system.