# Bash to find files under directory and goto directory and compile

Tags: bash

All 4gl files are located in their own directory under dir1. I need to compile these 4gl files to be 4ge. Normally I compile follow this step;
cd ~/dir1/file1/
build file1.4ge  # file locates in this folder is file1.4gl

But what if I need to create a loop script to find these 4gl files in each directory under dir1 and then change directory to the directory that found the file first, compile it using command "build file_name.4ge", then move to the next 4gl file. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621187/how-to-search-subdirectories-for-c-files-and-compile-them-shell-scripting) should help you with your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search subdirectories for .c files and compile them (shell scripting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621187/how-to-search-subdirectories-for-c-files-and-compile-them-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$ find ~/ -type f -name "*.4gl" -exec sh -c \ 'cd $(dirname $1);build $(basename $1 .4ge)' sh {} \;
```